# Python KeyError: 0 when using D2VTransformer

Tags: python, dataframe, pipeline, gensim, doc2vec

I am getting KeyError:0 when running this code in python:

```
full_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Here is the completed code:

```
from gensim.sklearn_api import D2VTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, Pipeline 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

name_pipeline = Pipeline( steps = [ 
                              ( 'feature_selector', FeatureSelector(['name']) ),
                              ( 'feature_transformer', D2VTransformer() ) ] )

description_pipeline = Pipeline( steps = [ 
                              ( 'feature_selector', FeatureSelector(['description']) ),
                              ( 'feature_transformer', D2VTransformer() ) ] )

X_pipeline = FeatureUnion( transformer_list = [ 
                                                  ( 'name_pipeline', name_pipeline ), 
                                                  ( 'description_pipeline', description_pipeline ) ] )

#Split up the train and test data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)

clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, class_weight='balanced', solver='lbfgs', max_iter=1000, multi_class='multinomial')

full_pipeline = Pipeline( steps = 
                         [ ( 'pipeline', X_pipeline),
                          ( 'model', clf ) ] )

full_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
19 frames
<ipython-input-14-0ddbaedffb67> in <module>()
     25                           ( 'model', clf ) ] )
     26 
---> 27 full_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    350             This estimator
    351         """
--> 352         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    353         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
    354                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    315                 message_clsname='Pipeline',
    316                 message=self._log_message(step_idx),
--> 317                 **fit_params_steps[name])
    318             # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    319             # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    353 
    354     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 355         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    356 
    357     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    714     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    715         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 716             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    717         else:
    718             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    910             sum of n_components (output dimension) over transformers.
    911         """
--> 912         results = self._parallel_func(X, y, fit_params, _fit_transform_one)
    913         if not results:
    914             # All transformers are None

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _parallel_func(self, X, y, fit_params, func)
    940             message=self._log_message(name, idx, len(transformers)),
    941             **fit_params) for idx, (name, transformer,
--> 942                                     weight) in enumerate(transformers, 1))
    943 
    944     def transform(self, X):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1001             # remaining jobs.
   1002             self._iterating = False
-> 1003             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1004                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1005 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    832                 return False
    833             else:
--> 834                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    835                 return True
    836 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    751         with self._lock:
    752             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 753             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    754             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    755             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    199     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    200         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 201         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    202         if callback:
    203             callback(result)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    580         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    581         # arguments in memory
--> 582         self.results = batch()
    583 
    584     def get(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 
    258     def __len__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    254         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    255             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 256                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    257 
    258     def __len__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    714     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    715         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 716             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    717         else:
    718             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    391                 return Xt
    392             if hasattr(last_step, 'fit_transform'):
--> 393                 return last_step.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params)
    394             else:
    395                 return last_step.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params).transform(Xt)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    554         else:
    555             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
--> 556             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
    557 
    558 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gensim/sklearn_api/d2vmodel.py in fit(self, X, y)
    158 
    159         """
--> 160         if isinstance(X[0], doc2vec.TaggedDocument):
    161             d2v_sentences = X
    162         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2993             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2994                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2995             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2996             if is_integer(indexer):
   2997                 indexer = [indexer]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

Does anyone know why might this happen? I think it has to do with D2VTransformer because when I'm running the code below I'm getting the same error:

```
model = D2VTransformer(min_count=1, size=5)
docvecs = model.fit_transform(X_train)
```

But when trying to select only one column from the dataframe:

```
docvecs = model.fit_transform(X_train['name'])
```

it doesn't throw an error and that is why when I created the pipelines I've only used one column, but still getting the error.

This is how [X_train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87d5Q.png) looks.

```
name    description
9107    way great entrepreneur push limit help succeed  way great entrepreneur push limit
7706    dit het team week week  dit het team week week
3995    decorate home jewel tone    feel bold colour choice inspire fill home abun...
5220    attic meat district attic meat district
3412    tee apparel choose design item clothe accessory piece inde...
... ... ...
3830    marque web designer mode    marque web designer
3261    design holiday rest bite try lear magazine dai...   design holiday rest bite try lear
2415    hallucinatory house father spirit   music room hold tower season rug produce early...
7223    jacket rise jacket rise
4697    cupcake bake explorer   love love chocolate cupcake top kind easy foll...
```

And some more details about X_train:

```
X_train.shape
(7159, 2)

X_train.dtypes
name           object
description    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: How is `X` created, and what's some representative data? Also, I'm not seeing in your error stack any frame/line that corresponds with your triggering code. Have you slimmed the stack somehow? (I recommend showing just the minimal triggering code, and the full error stack, to clearly identify each line of your code, & library code, implicated in the error.)

Comment: @gojomo I have edited the post and included two images, one that shows the training data, **X_train**, and one that shows the line that throws the error. In the code above when running `full_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)` throws the same error included in the image, when I'm not using the pipeline. That is exactly the error I'm getting, it might be showing only that because I'm using Google Colab.

Comment: Thanks, though it's way more helpful to see the data or error stacks as text than screenshots. (It will also ensure the question still makes sense if the image-hosting goes away, and make the question more findable by others in the future with the same problem.) Also, those stacks are a bit strange & incomplete compared to usual Python error stacks, not showing all frames, nor a line-of-code for each frame. Is there a way to have it show more, either via clicking parts of the interface (like that '4 frames' divider in the middle) or selecting other options for more-plain output?

Comment: @gojomo Thanks, you were right the frame divider can be expanded, I have updated the error message above. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Which exact code is this full error stack triggered by? (Ideally it'd an exact minimal example that immediately precedes it – such as the 2-lines you show later ending with a `fit_transform()` – but it appears to be some code that has a `fit()` on line 10, preceded by a comment line that isn't shown in your other code. So, it's not certain it was generated by the exact other code you've shared.) What happens if you check the size (& other aspects) of `X_train` before passing it to `fit`/`fit_transform`?

Comment: @gojomo Sorry for the confusion, I have run it again and updated the code and the error. I have also included the shape of `X_train`. Is this happening because I'm using D2V transformer on `X` but not on `y`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was a recent [bug](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2556) and [fix](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/commit/289a6ca52eaebd3b8fe39c3655e78cd6579b774a) in `gensim` (October 2019, and not yet in any official release) to make `D2VTransformer` more tolerant of some Pandas Series as data sources, to resolve exactly the same exception as you've hit.

The line of code changed is exactly the one shown in your extended error-stack - line 160 of `d2vmodel.py`, testing `X[0]`.

I would suggest grabbing the raw source of the latest version of `d2vmodel.py` to use locally (instead of importing from `gensim.sklearn_api`), and check if that resolves your issue. See:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/sklearn_api/d2vmodel.py